# .htaccess Block direct access to subdirectories, but allow them to be called via JQuery/images/etc

Tags: apache, security, .htaccess

My main index.php calls a couple of scripts via JQuery from a subdirectory. I need to block direct access to any files in this directory, but allow them to be accessed by index.php. I have tried the simply:

`deny from all`

approach, but this blocks even Jquery from loading the script. There is also an `/images` subdirectory that needs to be blocked from direct access. `deny all` disallows the image from being called in any way. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use the file-functions of php to get the content of the protected files, so only your php-file (e.g. index.php) is able to handle with the files of the protected dir.

useful functions are:

[file_get_contents()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)

[fread()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php)

...

then you can include the js-code in your output-html or get the content out as image (then you should take a look at the [header()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) function.